# How to know if instance was updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

I have an `update` action that renders an `edit` action upon successful updates.

```
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { render :edit, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my view, I would like to do conditionally show/hide some page elements depending on if the `@project.update` was successful or not.

A solution I've considered is rewriting the method to something like:

```
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    @was_successfully_updated = false    # ADDED
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        @was_successfully_updated = true # ADDED
        format.html { render :edit, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
```

I feel like Rails may have something built in to indicate this.

Is there a way i can interrogate my `@project` instance to know:

1. It's not a NEW unsaved record
2. It contains data that was successfully updated

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. It's not a NEW unsaved record

```
@model.new_record?  # the opposite of `@model.persisted?`
```

#### 2. It contains data that was successfully updated

```
@model.changes      # => {"column" => ["oldValue", "newValue"]}
```

Comment: Does this flow through to associations?  (by way of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`)

Comment: With the `new_record?` it only checks the model the method has been called on. With regards to the second question - no, it only deals with the model's own attributes, not associated model attributes. [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) you may find more examples.

Comment: I'm not sure if your answer is correct.  If possible, could you please take a look at this question showing it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817386/model-instances-not-flagged-as-changed-after-successful-attribute-update