# Model instances not flagged as changed after successful attribute update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to do conditionally show/hide some elements in one of my views depending on if a `@project.update` changed attributes or not.

I am trying to understand WHY my model instances are not being marked as changed after a successful attribute update.

It appears that `ActiveModel::Dirty` is not properly indicating my model's attributes have changed or more likely I'm not using it properly.

Here is an annotated log of a `PATCH` request I make to my `ProjectController#update` action.  In it you will see that the attributes change but the model instance does not reflect it. For what it's worth, the controller was generated by a Rails scaffold operation.  There's nothing out of the ordinary.

```
#
# FORM SUBMITTED FROM BROWSER WITH A CHANGE TO THE ATTRIBUTE NAMED "title"
#
Started PATCH "/projects/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-23 15:47:38 -0700
Processing by ProjectsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0JH/fEKx+Qk6mOY+eVTteKQUKrZUVXroKzMxuztrTzE/voI+PtzmQnJLGVM5bgdmzJyHDpAon3dzcvvjJ3yEtQ==", "project"=>{"title"=>"changed"}, "commit"=>"Update Project", "id"=>"2"}
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]

# 
# DEBUGGER KICKS IN BEFORE THE UPDATE HAS HAPPENED
#
[40, 49] in app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
   40:
   41:   # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
   42:   # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
   43:   def update
   44:     byebug
=> 45:     respond_to do |format|
   46:       if @project.update(project_params)
   47:         format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
   48:         format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
   49:       else

#
# PROJECT TITLE IS STILL UNMOLESTED
#
(byebug) @project
<Project id: 2, title: "ORIGINAL_TITLE", created_at: "2016-04-23 22:47:30", updated_at: "2016-04-23 22:47:30">
# PROVE PARAMS CONTAIN A CHANGED ATTRIBUTE
(byebug) project_params
<ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"changed"} permitted: true>

#
# TRIGGER UPDATE AND PERSIST NEW TITLE
#
(byebug) @project.update(project_params)
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "projects" SET "title" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "projects"."id" = ?  [["title", "changed"], ["updated_at", 2016-04-23 22:48:13 UTC], ["id", 2]]
   (3.5ms)  commit transaction
true

#
# WAT?
#
(byebug) @project.changes
{}
(byebug) @project.changed?
false
(bye bug)
```

Here is my `ProjectsController#update` action (standard Rails scaffold):

```
# app/controllers/projects_controller.rb

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    byebug
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The corresponding view form (also from generated scaffolding):

```
# app/views/projects/_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(project) do |f| %>
  <% if project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% project.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can u post your `update` method and `form`

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this? is it like you want to do something after updation if there was any changes?

Comment: I added more info answering both requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to achieve something if there were any changes made during an update.

If that's the case, you could do something like this :

Use a `after_save` or `after_update` callback as necessary for the model and within your callback, if you check `self.changes` or `self.changed?` you'd get expected results.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Let me check again

Comment: could you try using `update_attributes` instead of `update`

Comment: @BillyBlobSnortin You're right again. Please see my updated answer for a solution.

Comment: Is this a bug in rails?